# How do I store an array of a particular type into my settings file?

Tags: .net, settings, settings.settings

For some reason, I can't seem to store an array of my class into the settings.  Here's the code:

```
            var newLink = new Link();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Links = new ArrayList();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Links.Add(newLink);
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

In my Settings.Designer.cs I specified the field to be an array list:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public global::System.Collections.ArrayList Links {
        get {
            return ((global::System.Collections.ArrayList)(this["Links"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Links"] = value;
        }
    }
```

For some reason, it won't save any of the data even though the Link class is serializable and I've tested it.

Comment: "I can't seem" How do you see that? Is an exception thrown? Is the list empty when loading? Is is empty without reloading?

Comment: The list is empty with no exceptions thrown.  Somehow it isn't serializing my Links.

Comment: Is the data contained in the settings file (it's an XML file so you can easily check)?

Comment: I checked the user.config and there are no Links contained in the array.

Comment: Here's the user.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <AdminTool.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Links" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </AdminTool.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>

Interestingly, I tried to write an array of integers and it worked fine. I wonder what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the source of the problem.  Simply using a plain Array won't cut it. After thinking about it, the deserializer wouldn't know what type to deserialize the array items to.  I failed to see that the array required strong typing. The designer lead me to foolishly believe it was a plain generic array:

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public List<Link> Links
    {
        get {
            return ((List<Link>)(this["Links"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Links"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I had to make these changes in the Settings.Designer.cs and not from the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Link class is either correctly XML-serializable or that it has a typeconverter to string (which is preferred when using application.settings files).

I'd assume that something in your types will not transform into the XML-serialization format. And your user.config shows that it doesn't have any string typeconverter available.