# How to save changes to ObservableCollection stored in Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, wpf

Playing with a simple world clock program has led me to a problem of how to persist a custom `ObservableCollection` of `Clock` objects between program runs.  I can successfully save other setting types such as Strings, Doubles and Boolean but the `ObservableCollection` is not saved between program sessions.

No errors are thrown, debugger values appear to be updating fine (`Properties.Settings.Default.SavedClocks` count increases), and the clocks are added to the displayed list with no problems.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681957/trouble-saving-a-collection-of-objects-in-application-settings) has led me to the current structure of code below.

---

[image]

---

**Settings.Designer.cs** *- Manually created*

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public ObservableCollection<Clock> SavedClocks
{
    get{
        return ((ObservableCollection<Clock>)(this["SavedClocks"]));
    }
    set{
        this["SavedClocks"] = value;
    }
}
```

---

**Clock** class definition

```
[Serializable]
public class Clock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string m_LocationName { get; set; }
    public TimeZoneInfo m_TimeZone { get; set; }

    public Clock(){}

    public Clock(TimeZoneInfo tz, string name)
    {
        m_TimeZone = tz;
        m_LocationName = name;
    }

    //.... Other methods removed for brevity
}
```

---

**Main Window Initialized**

```
namespace WorldClock
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.SavedClocks == null)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.SavedClocks = new ObservableCollection<Clock>
                {
                    //When list is empty, default with local clock
                    new Clock(System.TimeZoneInfo.Local, System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName)
                };

                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = Properties.Settings.Default.SavedClocks;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Adding new clock to observable collection** (from drop down list)

```
private void btn_AddRegion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeZoneInfo tz = timeZoneCombo.SelectedItem as TimeZoneInfo;

    Properties.Settings.Default.SavedClocks.Add(new Clock(tz, tbx_RegionName.Text));
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

---

**XAML** *- Don't think any of it would be useful but here is the ListView I'm setting the ItemSource of*

```
<ListView  Name="lvDataBinding">
```

Comment: For storing data, the collection doesn't need to be observable. You could easily initialize an ObservableCollection from a stored List or array during application startup. See also this post about storing custom types in Application Settings: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/customappsettings.aspx

Comment: @Clemens - The post you linked is a good source and I've followed it to the letter but unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue with data not being persistent between runs.  Trying a different type is an option but I'm interested in knowing why my approach isn't working as expected. Thks

Comment: Your Clock class should probably have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Clemens - Actually, I have that already but accidentally stripped it out when posting.  Posted now.  Thanks for the thought

Comment: @PortlandRunner Try remove INPC from Clock class.

Comment: I also changed the type in `Settings.settings` - `Type="System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection&lt;Clock&gt;" Scope="User"` - don't forget to escape the angle brackets. It compiled so that's a start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the `SettingsSerializeAs` attribute to the `SavedClocks` property of in Settings.Designer.cs to specify the the collection should be serialized as binary data:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs(System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute(null)]
public ObservableCollection<Clock> SavedClocks
{
    get
    {
        return ((ObservableCollection<Clock>)(this["SavedClocks"]));
    }
    set
    {
        this["SavedClocks"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That got me over the hump, thanks!  For anyone else following, I also needed to add `[field:NonSerialized]` to the `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` in my Clock class.

Comment: This did it for me as well!